# How would a 28 bit computer affect a UTF-32 encoded file?

Tags: unicode, encoding

If we had an imaginary 28 bit computer, would it cause any complications for UTF-32?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but the internal representation of the data string after decoding UTF-32 wouldn't be UTF-32.  For example, a file with UTF-32 data could be read in and each codepoint decoded and stored in a 28-bit word.  The maximum Unicode codepoint value fits in 21 bits.

Comment: In other words, simply chop off the top 4 bits.

Comment: @RickJames Depends...big endian or little endian?  It’s *slightly* more complicated than that and why I chose the word “decode”, plus insert any other encoding for “UTF-32” and the statement is still valid.